# How to show bootstrap modal with a validator on the page from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, vb.net, bootstrap-4

I have a ASP webforms page that has a server side requiredfieldvalidator on it and it prevents me from opening a bootstrap modal from code behind. If I visible=false the validator the the modal pops. But if the validator is visible the modal doesn't pop? Clicking on the link the modal pops either way but not on the server side button. What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?

P.S. The reason i'm using a server side control is because I need to populate the modal with data from the database and the button is set to NOT cause validation.

code looks like:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Test" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt_test"  Text="Error" CssClass="text-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_OpenModal" runat="server" Text="Open Modal" CauseValidation="false"  />
         <a href="#mdl_Test" data-toggle="modal">Show Modal</a>





    <div  class="modal" id="mdl_Test">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Time" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save changes</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
 Private Sub btn_OpenModal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_OpenModal.Click
        lbl_Time.Text = Now
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "", "$('#mdl_Test').modal('toggle');", True)
    End Sub
```